# Metodo App::setLocale() no laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel-5, i18n

Após organizar o meu código, testei para ver se funcionava para alteração de idiomas em tempo real com o método `App::setLocale()` não funciona, mas quando faco a mudança no arquivo `app.php` o *locale* ele funciona perfeitamente, isto traduzindo o meu site no idioma que eu altero manualmente.

Alguém poderia me explicar porque não consigo alterar a partir do código?

**Controller**

```
class LangController extends Controller
{
    public function switchLang($lang)
    {
        if(array_key_exists($lang, Config::get('languages')))
        {
            Session::set('app.locale', $lang);
        }
        return Redirect::back(); 
    }
}
```

Arquivo **Widdleware Language.php**

```
class Language
{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if (Session::has('app.locale')array_key_exists(Session::get('app.locale'), Config::get('languages'))) {
            App::setLocale(Session::get('app.locale'));
        }
        else 
        { // This is optional as Laravel will automatically set the fallback language if there is none specified
            App::setLocale(Config::get('app.fallback_locale'));
        }
        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

**Rota**

```
Route::get('lang/{lang}', ['as'=>'lang.switch', 'uses'=>'LangController@switchLang']);
```

Arquivo de kernel atualizado com o meu Middleware

```
\Birth\Http\Middleware\Language::class,

Arquivo languages.php que retorna os idiomas

return [
    'en' => 'EN',
    'fr' => 'FR',
    'ru' => 'РУ',
    'pt' => 'PT',
    'es' => 'ES',
];
```

**View**

```
<a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle active" data-toggle="dropdown">
         {{ Config::get('languages')[App::getLocale()] }}

</a>
@foreach (Config::get('languages') as $lang => $language)
  @if ($lang != App::getLocale())

  | <a class="link-a" href="{{ route('lang.switch', $lang) }}">{{$language}}</a> 

  @endif
@endforeach
```

Comment: Um link com a solução : http://mydnic.be/post/laravel-5-and-his-fcking-non-persistent-app-setlocale Outra coisa a ser observada é que no Kernel.php deve estar assim : \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class, \App\Http\Middleware\Language::class,

Answer (score 0):

Não sei se este é o problema, mas esta if está errada:

```
if (Session::has('app.locale')array_key_exists(Session::get('app.locale'), Config::get('languages'))) {
```

O corretor seria isto:

```
if (Session::has('app.locale') && array_key_exists(Session::get('app.locale'), Config::get('languages'))) {
    App::setLocale(Session::get('app.locale'));
}
else 
{ // This is optional as Laravel will automatically set the fallback language if there is none specified
    App::setLocale(Config::get('app.fallback_locale'));
}
```

Usa um pouco mais de variaveis locais pra guardar o que já executou e ficar mais fácil entender o que você mesmo fez, tente assim:

```
$locale = Session::has('app.locale') ? Session::get('app.locale') : false;

if ($locale && array_key_exists($locale, Config::get('languages'))) {
    App::setLocale($locale);
} else {
    App::setLocale(Config::get('app.fallback_locale'));
}
```

Comment: Fiz a alteracao conforme indicado acima, mas continua na mesma. Nao reporta nenhum erro, ele faz o load da pagina, mas nao traduz a pagina. Penso eu que deve estar a faltar alguma configuracao com o setLocale() na minha maquina ou coisa assim parecida, porque o getLocale() ele ta pegar automaticamente e apresenta o valor na minha view, so nao esta setar em tempo real o idioma selecionado. Com a sintaxe e a logica eu penso que esta tudo certo, so nao sei qual e problema que esta impedir que o setLocale() atera o valor do locale.

Comment: @FranciscoBizi a estrutura de pasta está correta? Como está acessando as urls?

Comment: Esse e a estrutura: pasta config/ app.php, pasta app/http/middleware/Language.php, pasta config/ languages.php. Testei a variavel que o meu controller recebe como parametro e apresentar numa outra view esta funcionando correctamente. Se o usuario clicar num idioma a variavel do parametro recebe a chave do mesmo idioma, mas ao incluir a variavel no Session::set('app.locale', $lang) ele nao modifica nada.

Answer (score 0):

Eis a solucao do problema exposto acima. Apos alguns dias de tentacao, felizmente consegui contornar a situacao do seguinte modo:
1. criei uma varial na view que receberia um valor retornado do controller.
2. Testo se a mesma variavel recebeu o valor ou nao.
3. Caso a variavel receba um valor, chamo na view o metodo App::setLocale($variavel) e passo a varial como parametro do metodo, que neste caso contem a chave de um dos idiomas e a pagina e traduzida para o idioma selecionado.

Aqui esta o codigo, pode ate ser que haja uma melhor maneira de o fazer, mas o importante e que esta a funcionar direito como eu queria.

```
  class ControllerL extends BaseController
  {
        use AuthorizesRequests, DispatchesJobs, ValidatesRequests;
        public function choose($lang)
        {
           return view('welcome',['Lang'=>$lang]);
        }
   }
```

routa

```
  Route::get('/{lang}','ControllerL@choose');
```

Variavel que recebe o valor na view

```
  {{isset($Lang) ? App::setLocale($Lang) : false}}
```

Resumindo, acho eu que o metodo setLocale() funciona em tempo real isto e mais para o client-side. Pelo menos foi o que pode notar.